# TextEdit keeps crashing

Tags: macos, crash, textedit

I am using TextEdit to edit some tcl files. periodically, or even frequently, but not always, when I go to save the file, I get a spinning beach ball. I tried launching text-edit via the command-line, but i was not imparted with any additional error information.

So what might be making TextEdit crash?
I have OSX 10.6.8 on an imac. I have all the updates my computer will allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out why TextEdit is crashing, your best bet is to pull up [Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_(OS_X)) and look for error messages from TextEdit.

That said, there are so many better text editors available on OS X.  Unless you have a really good reason for using TextEdit, I'd suggest trying any of these:

- Sublime Text: http://www.sublimetext.com/
- Atom: http://atom.io/
- TextMate: https://macromates.com/download
- Brackets: http://brackets.io/
- Text Wrangler: http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/
- BBEdit: http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/

Comment: Yeah I started using Geany  http://www.geany.org/  and it hasn't crashed again yet! I'll lookinto that console